# Joomla breaking Menu in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, drop-down-menu, joomla, navigation

I am desperate for a solution to my problem. I have a website I am working on that has a pure CSS dropdown menu. You can see it working (even in IE) here: http://www.ajacwebdesign.com/sites/r2giant439/

Here is where it gets weird! So I have the same menu and identical CSS inside of Joomla. No Modules or extensions installed. Just core Joomla and nothing else, and the menu works in all browsers but IE.

When I inspect the code I see that IE recognizes the html is there, but displays nothing. You can see this Joomla mystery here: http://www.ajacwebdesign.com/sites/joomlatest/

I would appreciate ANY help at all...heck I will take suggestions of any sort! I need to get this working so I can move on with the site, but its got me so frustrated....It just makes no sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

The page contains 2 `html` tags, so IE renders the page in `Quirks` mode.

Remove the redundant one and IE will render it in `Standards` mode and the menu will be displayed properly.

Comment: I tried this solution. Had me excited, but it did not seem to have any effect. :(

Comment: perhaps there is something to the head tag...? but if that were the case wouldn't it also be an issue on the test non-joomla page?

Comment: I can now see the menu in IE10. Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Well...you got me thinking in the right direction! The Doctype was not html5...I had forgot to change it. Thanks for getting me to think about this differently!